# How to combine multiple corrplot correlograms in R?

Tags: r, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

I calculated 17 correlograms using the `corrplot` function, I would like to merge them all into a single graph with 4 columns.

I tried the cowplot library but the graph was blank, and the pathwork library doesn't even work.

If it is possible to unite all, would it be possible to export the result?

Reproducible problem:

```
cor_mtcars<-cor(mtcars[,1:4],
                mtcars[,5:8],
                method = "spearman",
                use="pairwise.complete.obs")

p_mtcars<-corrplot(cor_mtcars,
                  method="color",
                  addCoef.col = "black",
                  number.cex=0.6,
                  tl.cex = 0.8,
                  addgrid.col = "grey",
         cl.cex=0.6,
         title = "Spearman Correlation Coefficients mtcars1",
         cex.main=0.8,
         mar=c(0,0,2,0))
p_mtcars


cor_iris<-cor(iris[,1:2],
                iris[,3:4],
                method = "spearman",
                use="pairwise.complete.obs")

p_iris<-corrplot(cor_iris,
                  method="color",
                  addCoef.col = "black",
                  number.cex=0.6,
                  tl.cex = 0.8,
                  addgrid.col = "grey",
         cl.cex=0.6,
         title = "Spearman Correlation Coefficients iris",
         cex.main=0.8,
         mar=c(0,0,2,0))
p_iris

library(cowplot)

p1<-cowplot::plot_grid(p_mtcars, p_iris, labels = "AUTO")

p1


library(patchwork)
 
(p_mtcars | p_iris)
```

output cowplot blank merge
[image]

while for pathwork library show a mensage error:
`Error in p_iris + p_mtcars : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Do you have any warning messaged?

Comment: yes for pathwork. i edited question.